# How to get calling convension of a function from type library?

Tags: visual-c++, com, calling-convention, typelib

How can I get the calling convention at runtime using type library whether using stdcall, cdecl, winapi or any other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a typelibrary is involved, you're using COM. COM always uses the same calling convention (on a given OS), so it isn't encoded into the type library. In the headers it shows up as `STDMETHOD` (or something like that -- I'm too lazy to check the exact spelling at the moment), but if memory serves it's basically equivalent to `__cdecl`. If memory serves, there's also an `_STDMETHOD` (or, again, something similar) that lets you specify a return type other than `HRESULT`.

Comment: It's __stdcall. They're not the same thing.